# Canon MP250 printer on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, canon

I have a Canon MP250 printer/scanner device, this is USB. It will not print using Ubuntu 20.04, however if I hook this printer up to an older laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 installed, it prints fine.

When I plug this printer into my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop, Ubuntu says it's installing the printer, and it's listed inside the printers settings area afterwards.

When I visit http://127.0.0.1:631/printers/MP250-series the printer shows up in there. When I try to print a test page from this area, I get this error:

```
Unsupported format "application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner".
```

If I go to "Printers" inside of Ubuntu settings area, and choose to print a test page, nothing happens.

Looking inside of the file`/usr/share/cups/mime/mime.types` I see this line is there:

```
application/pdf                 pdf regex(0,^[\n\r]*%PDF)
```

When I try to print a simple text file using gedit to this printer, these messages appear from `journalctl -xf`:

```
Feb 10 14:28:18 wayne-L530 dbus-daemon[880]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.8" (uid=115 pid=878 comm="avahi-daemon: starting up " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.352" (uid=1000 pid=105906 comm="/usr/bin/gedit --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Feb 10 14:28:18 wayne-L530 dbus-daemon[880]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.8" (uid=115 pid=878 comm="avahi-daemon: starting up " label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.352" (uid=1000 pid=105906 comm="/usr/bin/gedit --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
```

The device scans fine using Ubuntu 20.04 but does not print. What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 4):

The ppa:michael-gruz/canon does not working for Ubuntu 20.04 (it gives an 404 for the focal Release).

You only need to add the ppa fork:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
sudo apt-get update
```

and then install the printer + scanner drivers:

```
sudo apt install cnijfilter-mp250series 
sudo apt install scangearmp-mp250series
```

After that you can configure the printer via the "Printers" in your Desktop GUI.

Comment: This works for Canon MP270 in Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2):

I followed this article and was able to get my printer working:
https://www.ubuntupit.com/how-to-install-canon-printer-driver-in-ubuntu-linux/

Specifically, I added these repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, inside system settings -> Printers -> MP250 -> Printer Details
Click "Search Drivers"
This will find the drivers from the repo you installed, a pop-up will appear asking if you want to install the drivers. Click YES.

Printer started working.

**July 2022 Update**
Had to re-install my OS, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 still, but my old answer did not work. However, this did:

```
sudo apt-get install cups cups-client foomatic-db
```

Under "printer details" - manually pick the driver, and MP250 should be in the list.